# Store Bitmap from imageview to SD

Tags: android

i am trying to save a bitmap that is displayed on an imageview. what i understand is that i need to

1. convert bitmap to stream.
2. write that stream to a file on the sd card.

here is what i have done

```
try {
                   File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
                   File file = new File(path, "name.png");
                   FileOutputStream out = null;
                   if (file.exists()) {
                       // do something awesome

                   } else {

                       out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                       currentimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
                   }
                   out.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I am trying to change the file name saved i understand it will go in the FileOutputStream but not quite sure

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, the only issue is that you don't close your OutputStream.
You need to add

```
try {
    out.close();
} catch (IOExcetion ex) {
}
```

to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a filename by extending the path you get to the public pictures directory.

```
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File(path, "name.png"));
```

Or if you want to check if it already exists first:

```
File file = new File(path, "name.png");
if (file.exists()) {
    // do something awesome
    // perhaps save over top
    // perhaps pick another name
} else {
    // save it
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    currentimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
}
```

Comment: i tried FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path+"/test.PNG");
 . but if i want to check if the picture is saved to the sd card how can i browse to find it

Comment: yea i have that part handled but for some reason i cant find the picture in the gallery after i save it .. there are no errors or what so ever too any

Comment: You'll need to trigger a scan of the new file. Look here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html at the scanFile method.

Comment: any idea on the implementation of that ??

Comment: If you are targeting Android 2.2 or higher, just use the static scanFile method and pass in an array of files (in your case it's just a single array element) and the mimeTypes which belong to those files (in your case image/png). You can give it an empty callback if you don't care about the result. I'm away from my PC so I can't give actual code at the moment.

Comment: ok thank you i will try to figure it out and will let you know  . if i need an actual code